# List of buffers in view pane

Tags: buffers, navigation

I must be turning a corner because I keep thinking of moving my text drafts off my Windows machine and onto my Linux box to get the convenience of editing them in Vim instead of Notepad++.

One thing I am going to miss though is Notepad++'s buffer window on the left that shows all my files. I just click on a file to open it in the view. Sublime Text has a similar ability, I believe, although I do not use Sublime.

Is there a way to get a pane like this that would show all the buffers, for example, in Vim and have a number or something so you could quickly activate whichever one you want? In Notepad++ I usually have about 50 to 60 different text files loaded at any given time.

In Notepad++ this functionality is called "Document List Panel" (Settings / General / Document List Panel show), shown on the left below:

[image]

Comment: I think the [bufexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42) plugin can do this, but I never really tried it myself. Also see [this list](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Scripts) for some other options.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I am actually aware of that list and have investigated some of those plugins.The problem is that the list is unbelievably long, there are like 25 different buffer-related plugins. Also, using a plugin rather than native functionality always introduces complexity. Therefore, I was hoping for the voice of experience to help me figure out the simplest option.

Answer (score 7):

1. You can use GVim on Windows so Vim is not really a valid reason for switching to Linux.
2. You can display a list of buffers with `:ls`.
3. For the last time: **R**ead **T**he **F**antastic **M**anual.

Comment: :ls does not open a permanent pane, it just lists the buffers temporarily

Comment: You don't need it to be permanent, that's completely superfluous.

Comment: The problem with ls is that it lists all buffers. In case one has the following buffers opened: 1. terminal buffer, 2. NERDTree buffer, 3...100. Some regular file opened. Is there a way to list buffers corresponding to regular files only? Precisely I want to switch over file buffers and bind it to `Tab` to display it in a particular active viewport. This would be similar to what most `IDE`s have with their `CTRL+Tab` binding to go to the next tab pane.

Comment: @romainl What works for you doesn't work for everyone. That's why (good) software and programming languages and editors are so configurable. I think a persistent buffer list would be pretty useful. Anyone who uses Vim with tabs probably feels a similar way.

Answer (score 6):

I would also add that in gVim you can get a very close approximation to this feature. If you click on the buffers menu item and then click the "tear off" (`--✂-----`) button. It opens up a little window that shows you all your buffers and does pretty much what you want. You can also do this with `:tearoff Buffers`.

I.E.
[image: Buffer window]

Comment: I have been a little reluctant to get involved with gVim, both because I like to use the keyboard and I often use terminal sessions, so I would have to learn X11 forwarding, which I suspect is laggy and complicated. So, I am kind of hoping for a text-based solution.

Comment: @TylerDurden I don't know about X11 forwarding, but just because you use gVim doesn't mean you have to use the mouse. :P gVim is my main use of vim and I hardly *ever* use the mouse on it. You can even turn the mouse features off if you really wanted to.

Comment: I use gvim (7.4.461) e.g. on Linux. I don't find the "tear off" button. How do I get this to work on Linux? @romainl: `:ls` is too slow to be an alternative.

Comment: You can also try `:tearoff Buffers`

Comment: It looks like the `:tearoff` command is available on Windows only. You can still "tear off" menus by using the interface, but not with the command it seems...

Comment: Really? That seems very weird. I will have to try that when I get back to my Linux box. I know it only worked in gVim vs vim, but I've never seen a command that flat out didn't work on one OS vs another.

Comment: @Tumbler41 Yeah, I'm surprised too, but [`:help :tearoff`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_w32.txt.html#%3atearoff) is in `gui_w32.txt` and using it doesn't work. Didn't check the source to verify though.